# Regex: Match everything except string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the regex

```
^(.)+?domain\.com
```

which machtes

```
www.domain.com or
domain.com or
something.domain.com but
.domain.com too.
```

What I want is to "filter out" the possibility of ".domain.com". It should match [something].domain.com and domain.com but NOT .domain.com. (or ..domain.com). It should be a valid subdomain. What would be the correct regex to get this done?

Updated question to clarify requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This pattern [will do it](http://www.regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E(.%2B%5C.%7C)domain%5C.com&input=www.domain.com%0Adomain.com%0Asomething.domain.com%0A.domain.com%0Adomain.com%0Asub.domain.domain.com)

```
^([^.]+\.)*domain\.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - perfect! Exactly what I wanted. I'll accept it asap.

Comment: This will still allow e.g. `many.parts.domain.com` and even `..domain.com`. Up to you whether that is desirable.

Comment: @tripleee I believe `many.parts.domain.com` is perfectly OK to accept. `..domain.com` _does_ feel wrong.

Comment: ..domain.com is wrong that's true, but many.parts.domain.com would be right. Would there be a possibility to filter out .. (or ... or ....) out too?

Comment: @Andy see the Tripleee's answer + my suggestion.

Comment: `[something]` can be anything. So I this pattern.

Comment: My target is to match EVERY subdomain which is valid, but "." or ".." as subdomain wouldn't be valid. So I need to filter out these too. Did I overlooked the solution?

Comment: `((...)+|)` is sub-optimal.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: Thanks :) Looks now that it covers all possibilities for valid subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it will match `otherdomain.com` too. A better approach might be to allow zero or one occurrences of non-dot+ dot:

```
^([^.]+\.)?domain.com$
```

As suggested in a comment, to allow many levels of subdomains, change `?` to `*`.

Comment: I suggest `*` instead of `?`.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow multiple subdomains and the domain itself

```
^(.*\.)?domain.com&
```